# How to use new window's properties after opening workspace/folder

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing an extension in which I prompt the user for a folder in their file system and open that folder using

`await commands.executeCommand("vscode.openFolder",<Uri_to_open>,false)`

As described in the api docs (and whenever I open a folder in vanilla VSCode), the window is refreshed, removing all previously open files. I now want do stuff within the new window. Like `createTerminal` or use the outputChannel. I've tried both and neither run after the new folder has been opened and the window refreshed. If I use `true` within the executeCommand line, I can see these actions being performed on the "old" window, not in the window of my newly selected folder. 
**How do I ensure when I run `window.<function>`, I'm specifying the new window?**